# ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d. Consider increasing the input size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been trying to train a CNN model with facial data for creating emojies using facial expression.I'm actually new to machine learing. The code isn't actually my own but I keep getting this ValueError while trying to train the model.

> *ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 100, 100, 1] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.*

The code which I'm trying to run is:

```
def cnn_model():
    num_of_classes = get_num_of_classes()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(10, 10), strides=(10, 10), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    filepath="cnn_model_keras.h5"
    checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint1]
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
    return model, callbacks_list
```

num_of_classes value = 12

image_x,image_y = 100

Answer (score 0):

I reorganized your code,  you are defining  a function to build the model, It would be better to keep only what is related to the model architecture and keep the callbacks and model plotting out of the function.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dropout,Dense
from tensorflow.keras  import optimizers
import numpy as np

def cnn_model():
    image_x = 100
    image_y = 100

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(10, 10), strides=(10, 10), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


########################
# Model summary
model = cnn_model()
model.summary()

#################### TEST
input = np.ones((1,100,100,1))
print("Output:", model.predict(input))
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 96, 96, 32)        832       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 96, 96, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 10, 10, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3200)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1024)              3277824   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 1024)              4096      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1024)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 12)                12300
=================================================================
Total params: 3,295,180
Trainable params: 3,293,068
Non-trainable params: 2,112
_________________________________________________________________
2022-07-03 15:15:36.927515: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Output: [[0.06614503 0.10535268 0.07621874 0.08486015 0.08070944 0.08046351
  0.06786356 0.06059184 0.10280456 0.05683669 0.12510006 0.09305366]]
```